# How to open a new window and send out a POST request with JSON data in the new window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, post

I am interested in opening a new window in my JavaScript. The window should send a POST request after opening. The steps that I tried are:

1. Create a new window object using `window.open()`.
2. Set a JavaScript function to execute on `window.onload`.
3. In the JavaScript function defined in step 2, send a XMLHttpRequest for POST data using JSON.

The problem is that the POST request is being sent in the same window and not on a new window.

Any ideas on what can be done or any alternative approach to follow.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: in  window.open(), give an empty html page to load, in there execute your javascript function